# How WhatsApp shows discussions so fast?

Tags: performance, react-native, chat, whatsapp

I am working on a chat app, and when I click on a discussion with more than 20 messages, it always take a little while to show the discussion.
On WhatsApp, there is NO timeout, even if the discussion is 5 years old, even if I have 500 discussions in my app. It seems that all discussions are preloaded... but I don't think it's the case, because it would burn too much memory, wouldn't it ?

So, beside choosing to show the last 20-30 messages, and beside having all the data in local storage (because I tried to, doesn't help), what is the technique WhatsApp uses to be able to load discussions so fast ?

Note: I am building my app in React Native.

Answer (score 3):

The way they do it is by using data adapters, database cursors, reusing views and keeping only required data in memory.

This allows application to only fetch and display limited amount of elements and data on the screen. When you scroll next page, items are loaded like a viewpager. When you scroll up it does the same in opppsite direction.

It's worth mentioning that these apps are natively implemented and have all the system level apis available to their disposal. You can do same with proper type bindings and call underlying apis at slight lower performance than pure native apis as javascript wrapper would call the api on behalf. There are some libraries to checkout which does the same.

That said reading docs would also help you further optimize rendering 
[Optimizing lists configuration: React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration)
Also checkout androids own ListView docs and techniques to optimise them and adapt them to your use case.